# MySQL Select Where All Relations are x

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two MySQL tables, j and t, with a third normalising table, jt.

```
t.tID

j.jID

jt.status
jt.tID
jt.jID
```

How can I select all j where all jt.status="x"? That is, I want to select when all jt of a j are x, not just when one or more jt of a j are x.

I think table t may be irrelevant in this.

(I hope I make myself understood, I'm finding it rather hard to explain. Comment questions if you want.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though you want the [`not exists`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) clause.

```
select jt.*
  from jt
 where not exists ( select 1 from jt where status <> 'x' and jID = jt.jID )
```

This selects everything from `jt` where not a single value that isn't `x` exists in that table.

Comment: This is on the right track, but jt (a table alias) is beyond the scope of the inner select. What should I do?

Comment: MySQL Error #1146 |It may help if I give the whole query.| SELECT * FROM `BAP_Jobs` j JOIN BAP_Customers c on j.CustomerID = c.CustomerID JOIN BAP_JobTask jt on j.JobID = jt.JobID JOIN BAP_Tasks t on jt.TaskID = t.TaskID WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM jt WHERE Status <> 'Complete') AND j.Cash IS NULL AND j.CardNo IS NULL

Comment: @user1277170, replace `jt` with `jobtask` in your `where not exists`, You're selecting from a _table_ not the alias.

Comment: Then it selects every jt, regardless of JobID. (I.e the related rows.)

Comment: You want it for a specific `j` only? I've updated the answer again to restrict it to where the Job id is the same as the main table.